# Error creating channel using testnetwork on Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am currently learning about hyperledger fabric, and am having issues creating channels on the testnetwork. I am on windows 10 and have the latest version of the fabric and docker.

When I run this command  `./network.sh up createChannel` in my git bash I get this error

```
Error on outputChannelCreateTx: could not generate default config template: error parsing configuration: 
could not create application group: failed to create application org: 1 - Error loading MSP configuration 
for org Org1MSP: could not load a valid ca certificate from directory 
C:\fabric-samples\test-network\organizations\peerOrganizations\org1.example.com\msp\cacerts: 
CreateFile C:\fabric-samples\test-network\organizations\peerOrganizations\org1.example.com\msp\cacerts:
 The system cannot find the file specified.
+ res=1
Failed to generate channel configuration transaction...
Create channel failed
```

I am unsure as the source of this issue. Do I need to install the samples and binaries again? Is it where I'm running the commands?

Comment: `could not load a valid ca certificate from directory` You wrote that this log occurred. If so, have you checked that `C:\fabric-samples\test-network\organizations\peerOrganizations\org1.example.com\msp\cacerts` exists?

Comment: Please write the content and results you tried. If you thought `Do I need to install the samples and binaries again?` as in your question, you actually try installing again. then upload the results.

Comment: Seems like you shoud use git bash for windows and replace all your paths to linux like ones i.e. instead of:

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that you will get more troubles cause you're using **Windows 10**. Even if you use git-bat (or
Cygwin like, etc), you should aware that most of script was written for linux (especially for **ubuntu-based linux**). Next step, when you work with chaincode-nodejs, it will install some required libraries, some only works on Linux OS. Please consider switching to Linux

P/s . I'm using ubuntu 20.04 LTS for Fabric 2.2. It works perfect.

Comment: This seems at least partly to be a correct answer. When specifying crypto-config.yaml and configtx.yaml use linux slashes "/" instead of windows slashes "\". And avoid windows hard drives, use relative paths. Run all the platform specific binaries from e.g. git bash for Windows.

Comment: Would you think that if I used the fabric with ubuntu through WSL on windows 10 that it would resolve this issue?

Comment: Not sure yet, 7 months ago I tried but failed. Don't know if Windows 10's WSL is  better now